# CSS tables: prevent a table with empty cells from collapsing into a single line?

Tags: html, css

I've got a border around all the TDs, but because they only contain hidden elements, they collapse into a single line. Is there any way to have them take up the width of the table without setting height and width explicitly?

```
i.e. height: 200px; width: 200px;
```

I've also tried other promising sounding styles like `empty-cells:show` to no avail. Ideally, I'd like for the cells to automatically size to fill up the table's height / width.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. A live demo might also be helpful (e.g., jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options, you can't define specific height for cells via CSS, but you can define min-width for the cells (without setting a width for the whole table). Let's say your table has **.mytable** class, the cells will appear if you add this code:

```
.mytable td {
  min-width: 80px;
}
.mytable td::before {
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

We're adding here a min width for the table cells, plus adding a pseudo element (specifically a non-breaking spacing) inside the cells, so we add "invisible content" to the cell. This will apply for all cells, if you want to be applied to specific cells, you'll need to do that trough a class.

Hope this helps